# What is wrong with my Galaxy Tab A model SM-T380A

Tags: applications

Galaxy Tab A Model SM-T380 will not shut off and has info on screen such as Odin Mode ( HighSpeed) Current binary, system status, FAP LOCK, OEM LOCK, WARRANTY VOID: 0x0, QUALCOMM SECUREBOOT, AP SWREV:S1,T1,R1,A2,P1, SECURE DOWNLOAD

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know that, Its the download mode of Samsung phones. To get out of there just hold `power button` + `home button` + `volume down` if it doesn't work try holding all the buttons or `volume up` + `power button` + `home button` together.